# react big calendar not displaying events

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

Two days ago I created a cal with events from my database and it worked just fine. now, not even the basic setup works with dummy events evn though my events print properly to the console.

```
export default function CalendarModal({ onClose }) {
  const [savedPosters, setSavedPosters] = useState<IPoster[]>([]);
  const [profile] = useRecoilState(profileState);
  const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [events, setEvents] = useState<
    {
      title: string;
      start: Date;
      end: Date;
    }[]
  >([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsReady(false);
    const storedProfile = localStorage.getItem("userProfile");
    if (storedProfile) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isReady) {
      makeEvents();
    }
  }, [isReady]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    await getUserLikes();
    setIsReady(true);
  };

  const getUserLikes = async () => {
    try {
      const likesResp = await fetch(actual backend call
      );
      if (likesResp.ok) {
        const likes = await likesResp.json();
        setSavedPosters(likes.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching likes:", error);
    }
  };

  const makeEvents = () => {
    const newEvents = [
      ...savedPosters.map((poster) => {
        const startDate = moment(poster.startDate).toDate();

        const endDate = poster.endDate
          ? moment(poster.endDate).toDate()
          : moment(poster.startDate).toDate();

        const event = {
          title: poster.title!,
          start: startDate,
          end: endDate,
        };
        return event;
      }),
    ];
    setEvents(newEvents);
  };

  const customStyle = {
    minHeight: 500,
    width: 700,
    fontFamily: "'quicksand', sans-serif",
  };

  const eventStyleGetter = (event, start, end, isSelected) => {
    const style = {
      border: "none",
      borderRadius: "0",
      backgroundColor: isSelected
        ? "var(--dark-purple70)"
        : "var(--dark-purple100)",
    };
    return {
      style,
    };
  };



  return (
{modal creation} ...
          {events.length > 0 && (
            <ChakraProvider>
              <Calendar
                localizer={localizer}
                events={events}
                defaultView="week"
                views={["day", "week", "month"]}
                startAccessor="start"
                endAccessor="end"
                style={customStyle}
                eventPropGetter={eventStyleGetter}
              />
            </ChakraProvider>
         )}
  );
}
```

I tried creating a basic calendar with dummy events and they no longer show up either. I've also set some custom styling such as the height. My calendar was displaying properly a few days ago and now no events show up. The main change was that the profile page now allows for editing, but that's a separate component to the calendar.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).